# R write.table remove 0:00:00 from Timestamps

Tags: r, datetime

I am using same code for years for monthly reporting. But after moving to R 4.3.0, write.table starts to remove time part from timestamp, but only in midnight. So only 00:00:00 disappear in data.

Sample of csv output:

```
"date";"koeficient";"data"
2023-04-01;0,679422194464945;10
2023-04-01 01:00:00;0,745481825878732;8
2023-04-01 02:00:00;1,10325898660521;6
2023-04-01 03:00:00;0,805619002060303;5
```

In R I have everything in correct POSIXct format, just export break my data format

Does anyone have same problem and can I replace write.table with something else? I need to export data to csv with ";" as a delimiter and "," as a decimal.

I tried some dplyr, but some cannot force decimal to "," and those excel_csv produce mess.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you try specifying the format in the step before you write the CSV, e.g. `format(as.POSIXct(c("2023-04-01 00:00:00", "2023-04-01 01:00:00")), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")`?

Comment: For `;`/`,` use `write.csv2()` or `readr::write_csv2()` . Same applies for reading, in `*csv2()` functions default  delimiter is `;` and decimal separtor is `,`

Comment: Hello, before writing to csv, I used lubridate dmy_hm(raw_data). So i got POSIXct format, where I can see first value "2023-04-01 00:00:00". No problem.

I tried write.csv2 - result is with the same issue
With write_csv2 I got correct data, but in this format "2023-04-01T00:00:00Z" which is not good, because in next step I am concatenating it to large dataset with "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss" format.

Problem is, that I have same script for like 3 years and now with R upgrade it started to do a problem. Downgrading R solved my problem...

Comment: I have the same problem. For me downgrading R is not an option. How come that the behaviour of write.table changed with an upgrade of R? Is this a bug in this version and will be fixed in future versions? Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to correct the problem you have by adding one line of code before the `write.table` line of code:

```
df$date<-as.character(format(df$date))
```

after this, `00:00:00` is kept even at midnight

Comment: Yes, this also works for me.  I don't even need the as.character().  I'm not sure why, but this definitely fixes the issue.  I used write.csv, but I think it works with write.table also.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/issues/1184#issuecomment-838429293 mentions custom `output_column.POSIXt()`, which might be a viable option ( and hopefully does not introduce other issues ...)

```r
library(readr)
sample_data <- read_csv2(
'"date";"koeficient";"data"
2023-04-01;0,679422194464945;10
2023-04-01 01:00:00;0,745481825878732;8
2023-04-01 02:00:00;1,10325898660521;6
2023-04-01 03:00:00;0,805619002060303;5', show_col_types = FALSE)
#> ℹ Using "','" as decimal and "'.'" as grouping mark. Use `read_delim()` for more control.

# write_csv2 standard behaviour, ISO8601 with a UTC timezone: 
# format(x, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OSZ", tz = "UTC", justify = "none")
# https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/9558d899b7e8c592be339bfc31ec35593ccf20ca/R/write.R#L411
cat(format_csv2(sample_data))
#> date;koeficient;data
#> 2023-04-01T00:00:00Z;0,679422194464945;10
#> 2023-04-01T01:00:00Z;0,745481825878732;8
#> 2023-04-01T02:00:00Z;1,103258986605210;6
#> 2023-04-01T03:00:00Z;0,805619002060303;5

# lets remove T & Z:
output_column.POSIXt <- function(x, name) {
  format(x, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "UTC", justify = "none")
}
registerS3method("output_column", "POSIXt", output_column.POSIXt)

# check results:
cat(format_csv2(sample_data))
#> date;koeficient;data
#> 2023-04-01 00:00:00;0,679422194464945;10
#> 2023-04-01 01:00:00;0,745481825878732;8
#> 2023-04-01 02:00:00;1,103258986605210;6
#> 2023-04-01 03:00:00;0,805619002060303;5

# and test with write_csv2:
write_csv2(sample_data, "tmp.csv")
cat(read_file("tmp.csv"))
#> date;koeficient;data
#> 2023-04-01 00:00:00;0,679422194464945;10
#> 2023-04-01 01:00:00;0,745481825878732;8
#> 2023-04-01 02:00:00;1,103258986605210;6
#> 2023-04-01 03:00:00;0,805619002060303;5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>