# write.zoo() changed behavior since R 4.3.0: as.character.POSIXct() changed?

Tags: r, zoo, posixct

Sunday seemed to be a good day to update `R` from version 4.2.3 to 4.3.2 (on Win 10) to start with something up-to-date into a new week.

I was using the `zoo` package for some time series writing to basic text files for saving data. This worked for years, but after the above upgrade I encountered a change in the output where suddenly midnight times are left out:

Code to test (using `zoo` version 1.8.12):

```r
library(zoo)
write.zoo(
  zoo(
    c(46, 47),
    c(as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 01:00:00"))
  )
)
```

With R prior to 4.3.0 the result looks like:

```r
"2023-11-26 00:00:00" 46
"2023-11-26 01:00:00" 47
```

But starting with 4.3.0 it changed to:

```r
"2023-11-26" 46
"2023-11-26 01:00:00" 47
```

As documentation of `zoo` says that `write.zoo()` is a convenience function for `write.table()` I tried to substitute with this getting proper results (with midnight timestamps) again:

```r
write.table(
  zoo(
    c(46, 47),
    c(as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 01:00:00"))
  )
)
```

outputs

```r
"2023-11-26 00:00:00" 46
"2023-11-26 01:00:00" 47
```

under any mentioned version of `R`.

So it seems like the `write.zoo` function has been broken by R >= 4.3.0, but the story continues...

As one can see in `zoo` [sources](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/zoo/R/read.zoo.R?revision=1133&root=zoo#l289) this function is rather simple and produces a `data.frame` from the zoo object by copying the index while using `as.character()`.

Testing again this very simple call on POSIXct objects

R <4.3.0:

```r
> as.character(c(as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 01:00:00")))
[1] "2023-11-26 00:00:00" "2023-11-26 01:00:00"
```

R >=4.3.0:

```r
> as.character(c(as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 01:00:00")))
[1] "2023-11-26"          "2023-11-26 01:00:00"
```

tells me, that this might be the reason for failure of `write.zoo()`

Now I'm puzzled because that is very basic R-functionality which was not mentioned to be changing in the [R News](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/4.3.0/NEWS.R-4.3.0.html). The output also looks awkward - why should there be two different formats be produced?

There is another question on [R write.table remove 0:00:00 from Timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76259729/r-write-table-remove-00000-from-timestamps) which uses `write.table()` directly on `data.frame` (so no `zoo` here) and yields the same results also in my case:

```
> write.table(data.frame(Index = c(as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 00:00:00"), as.POSIXct("2023-11-26 01:00:00")), Value = c(46, 47)), row.names = FALSE)
"Index" "Value"
2023-11-26 46
2023-11-26 01:00:00 47
```

So obviously my "workaround" by using `write.table()` on `zoo` objects only works because those objects are different internally. Unfortunately is beyond my understanding of `R` as well as if the `as.character()` behavior is intended and useful.

Any further explanation from the community on this?

Comment: There is a mention of changes to `as.character(<POSIXt>)` in the NEWS.

Comment: `print.POSIXt` has forever dropped the time from midnights. Maybe you should see if there are changes in `print.zoo`

Comment: Also consider using `xts` / writing as an `xts` -- this is a pretty natural specialisation of `zoo` that works well for `POSIXct` types.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Using `as.character(index(x))` within `write.zoo()` is definitely not a good idea. I will put together a fix.

Comment: @Axeman @IRTFM: I had seen that point, but a) did not link the NEWS on `POSIXt` so closely to `POSIXct` and also didn't expect the reported result with "more in line" behaviour of `as.character()`. Thanks for pointing me there.
So `as.character()` has been changed to leave out "as much as possble"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this problem. As others have already pointed out in the comments, the issue was triggered by a change in behavior of `as.character()` for `POSIXt` object.

I have just committed an update to `write.zoo()` on R-Forge which now uses `format(index(x))` rather than the old `as.character(index(x))` (which never was an ideal choice to begin with).

The update can be installed from R-Forge via

```
install.packages("zoo", repos="https://R-Forge.R-project.org")
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. For clarification to an not so experienced R-guy: Why is `as.character()` a bad choice there?

Comment: The function `as,character()` coerces each element of a vector but `format()` formats the entire vector assuring a common layout.